# "ctrl + ; (semicolon)" not inserting date in google sheets instead showing underlined e in ubuntu 22.04?

Tags: ubuntu, google-sheets, keyboard-shortcuts, emoji

I use the shortcut ctrl+; to enter date in google sheets, but after updating to Ubuntu 22.04 I am not able to enter date. In all text boxes if I press the combination, it is writing underlined e, which gets vanished after I press it again.
I have restarted the system, updated language and regional settings but cant get it work.

Answer (score 19, accepted):

Nothing clear was present online about this issue. I have solved it, so sharing if it could help.
that underlined e, was `emoji annotation` shortcut and that override the google sheet shortcut to insert current date.

To fix this, launched terminal, entered `ibus-setup`. A window for ibus preferences opened. There in emoji tab, shortcuts for emoji annotation is present.
It had both `ctrl+period` and `ctrl+semicolon` as added shortcuts. After deleting `ctrl+semicolon` the shortcut was again working perfectly.

[image]

In case you want to access the emoji annotation,`ctrl+period` is still present. After pressing the combination, when underlined 'e' is visible. Pressing spacebar, will open emoji menu, where you can select your preferred emoji too.

Hope this solved your issue.

[image]

Comment: U r genius Sir! Thanku.